# How do I solve this integral: $\displaystyle\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{(x^3-\arctan{x})^4}{1+x^2} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

The integral looks hyper complex and I don't think it has any analytic form at all, but we can try to expand this expression $(x^3-\arctan{x})^4$ in the numerator and get: $$(x^3-\arctan{x})^4=x^{12}-4x^9\arctan{x}+6x^6\arctan^2{x}−4x^3\arctan^3{x}+\arctan^4{x}$$

In fact, this does not give us much, because, despite the fact that even most of these functions can be integrated quite easily, there are a couple of integrals that are not clear how to count, they can be considered as a derivative with respect to a parameter, although how to count further, I don't get it. Maybe there is some kind of contour trick here?

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but... have you tried $\arctan x=t$ substitution?

Comment: Bear in mind that the indefinite integral of $(1+x^2)^{-1}$ is arctan$^{-1}(x)+c$.

Comment: @Tito Eliatron yeah ) But it didn't help me much.

Comment: Mahematica use $Li_n$ special function to solve it...

Comment: It is not pretty but it is doable. If $u=\tan^{-1} x$ then our integral becomes $$\int_0^{\pi/3} \left(\tan^3 u -u \right)^4 du.$$ Then perhaps use the $\int \tan^k x dx$ reduction formula and by parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @Chris Christopherson's comment
$$\left(\tan^3 (u) -u \right)^4=u^4+\tan ^{12}(u)-4 u^3 \tan ^3(u)+6 u^2 \tan ^6(u)-4 u \tan ^9(u)$$
The second antiderivative does not make serious problem since
$$\int \tan^n(u)\,du =\frac{\tan ^{n+1}(u)}{n+1}\, \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{n+3}{2};-\tan^2(u)\right)$$

The other are really unpleasant since they involve polylogarithm functions with complex arguments. Just have a look at [the result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28Tan%5Bu%5D%5E3-u%29%5E4%2Cu%5D).

For the definite integral, Wolfram Alpha just gives the numerical value but, using [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28Tan%5Bu%5D%5E3-u%29%5E4%2Cu%5D), we can obtain the exact formula.